# Is the next method referentially transparent for python Iterators?

Tags: python, functional-programming

It seems obvious to me that an Iterator object `X`, the methods:

- `X.next()` python 2.x
- `X.__next__()` python 3.x

are not referentially transparent because every invocation returns a different result.
But, I just need confirmation that I am correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that an iterator can return a different result on each call, so it cannot be called referentially transparent.

However, the aggregate actions of consuming an *iterable* can be referentially transparent eventhough the individual steps are not.  For example, `list('cat')` is deterministic and referentially transparent eventhough the implementation of *list* makes repeated *next* calls on the string iterator.

Answer (score 0):

It is as referentially transparent as `X` will let it be. The method itself does not change transparency, but the iterable can be as simple or as complex as desired.